# Geckodriver PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log' only with task scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver

I am trying to set up my python web scraper to run at a set time using task scheduler but I am getting this error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'` I have no idea why because it works fun when running the python script by using the batch file or just by double-clicking the .py file. Anyone have any ideas about why it only happens with task scheduler.

FYI: I am using a batch file that calls the python.exe and the .py script and this what task scheduler is using to trigger the script. I am using selenium and firefox.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by checking the Run with highest privileges and configure for Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue with Task Scheduler. I tried / and \ and other options (run with highest privileges" but still had issues. What worked for me was to cd into the directory within the bat file.

Previously, my .bat file was simply:

```
python "C:\path\to\some\directory\run.py"
```

I updated my .bat file to:

```
cd "C:\path\to\some\directory"
python run.py
```

Hopefully this helps others that run into this.